HTML Div container with rounded border & overflow:hidden, creates white pixel inside when another div displays background
Here is the code:


.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="background"></div> 
</div>



It produces the the view like this:

How can I get rid of the white ghost pixels between the background and the border?

You can use box-shadow it's because the box-shadow property is good option to make sharp and cleaned border without any white ghost pixels.


.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
}
    
.background {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="background"></div> 
</div>




That is because the container has the border, and the inner (background) div is "next to it" inside it.
The solution would be to define the border around the inner div.
For convenience, I've added a calc to calculate the difference by subtracting the border-width variable from the height and the width, like so:


:root{
--border-width: 2px;
}
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background: green;
  height: calc(100% - var(--border-width) * 2);
  width: calc(100% - var(--border-width) * 2);
  border: var(--border-width) solid red;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>



